# Why Can't I get my React App to work on Github Pages?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, github-pages

I am trying to host a simple React App in Github Pages, and I am then serving it to my domain, however I am unable to get it to work/load properly.

I am using `webpack --production` and I think this might be causing issues. (not sure though it's my first time attempting anything like this)

The error I see in my website's console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined
    at Object../src/App.js (App.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:68
    at bootstrap:68
```

If it helps this is my [repo](https://github.com/yamnel/Ron-Wisdom.github.io) and I am building the webpage from the `/docs` folder. The folders in it are the result of the build command `webpack --mode production`. The page is loaded [here](https://www.yamnel.com/)